# Validate incoming ISO 8583 Message at Schema level

Tags: java, validation, xml-parsing, iso8583, jpos

I am working on validating incoming iso 8583 message at schema level during parsing but i am facing issues in validating the type of the message.

This is the schema that i am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE isopackager PUBLIC
        "-//jPOS/jPOS Generic Packager DTD 1.0//EN"
        "http://jpos.org/dtd/generic-packager-1.0.dtd">

<isopackager>
  <isofield
      id="0"
      length="4"
      name="MESSAGE TYPE INDICATOR"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="1"
      length="16"
      name="BIT MAP"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_BITMAP"/>
  <isofield
      id="2"
      length="19"
      name="PAN - PRIMARY ACCOUNT NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
      id="3"
      length="6"
      name="PROCESSING CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="4"
      length="12"
      name="AMOUNT, TRANSACTION"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="5"
      length="12"
      name="AMOUNT, SETTLEMENT"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
<isopackager>
```

For field 2 (PAN Number) I should only get numeric value and for that i have specified the class `org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM` But this does not seem to be working as when I receive an incoming message with field 2 containing alphabets It still parses it successfully. I want this parsing to fail when it contains alphabets. Even for fields with `org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC` class accept alphabets in the fields

for eg:
field 2 : 12987658096472 (first 2 digits specify length, next 12 digits specify the value)
This is the correct Value.

12ABCD79365760 - This is the incorrect value but still it is being parsed successfully.

Can anyone please help me on how can i validate the datatype of the field values with schema itself ? Is there any other way we can achieve this ?

Comment: That is not a schema, it’s just an example document.  An [XML schema](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html) can be used to perform the validation you want.

Comment: Hi @VGR thanks for your response, do you have some examples that I can follow to create a DTD file to check data type. That would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: A DTD cannot enforce character content.  An XML schema can.

Comment: Oh Okay. Can you please refer me some more examples on how can I create an XML schema for my validation ? Thanks !

Comment: The official [XML Schema primer](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/) is a good place to learn how XML schemas work.